# Java WordCounter

Tags: java, locks

Hello I have a project for school where I must create a program in java that counts the words in one or more files. It should start a new thread for each new file. Its also supposed to have locks to protect the combined word counter and a counter for active threads. Ive tried researching locks, but im having trouble grasping the concept.
Here is what I was able to come up with so far.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args)throws InterruptedException {

        WordCount[] counters = new WordCount[args.length];
        for (int index = 0; index < args.length; ++index)
            {
                counters[index] = new WordCount(args[index]);
                counters[index].start();
            }
        int total = 0;
        for (WordCount counter : counters)
        {
            counter.join();
            total += counter.count;
        }

        System.out.println("Total:" + total);

    }

}


public class WordCount extends Thread {

    int count;

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        count = 0; //it will count the words
        ++count;

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't screenshot code, paste it. Also give WordCount code

Comment: Java has plenty of utilities built into the API that allows you to run concurrent tasks without having to deal with threads explicitly. Are you allowed to make use of those or does it have to be raw threads with explicit synchronisation.

Comment: It has to be raw threads, and the code has to be able to compile under the command line, so basically without an IDE

Comment: Ok. Might be worth adding that detail to the question. Just checking if you've read through the concurrency tutorial  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/ ? If I add an answer I don't want to go over material you're already aware of.

Comment: Yes I’ve read the concurrency tutorial but I’m having a hard time  understanding it, I took programming as an elective and unfortunately I’m struggling and would appreciate any pointers in the right direction to complete this assignment

Answer (score 0):

'Protecting' the word counter really just means preventing two threads from attempting to update the word counter at the same time. The simplest way to achieve that in Java is with the `synchronized` keyword:

```
class WordCounter {
    private int count = 0;

    public synchronized void incrementCount() {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Now if two threads call that method the JVM will force one to wait until the other completes.

Next you need a method that will count words in a file. That should be relatively simple. Something like:

```
private void countWords(Path path) {
    for (String line : Files.readAllLines(path)) {
        for (String word : line.split("\\s+")) {
            counter.incrementCount();
        }
    }
}
```

You'll need to cope with IO exceptions here.

Finally you need to create a thread for each file. At the moment you are subclassing the `Thread` class but a simpler solution is just to create a thread with the `Runnable` you need the thread to run:

```
for (Path path: myFiles) {
    Thread thread = new Thread(() -> counter.countWords(path));
    thread.run();
}
```

That's about it. I haven't added the code to keep a running thread count but it really just follows the same pattern.

Comment: An atomic variable would be more appropriate here I believe

Comment: @MatthewKerian you'll see in my comment above that I specifically asked if OP could use the various concurrency utilities. The answer was that only raw threads could be used.

Comment: My apologies @sprinter